# vb.net it may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net, authentication, error-handling, browser, webbrowser-control

Form1 Code:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.----------.org/login.php?")
    WaitForPageLoad()
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").InvokeMember("Click")

End Sub
```

the module code:

```
Private Property pageready As Boolean = False
```

## Region "Page Loading Functions"

```
Private Sub WaitForPageLoad()
    AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    While Not pageready
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    pageready = False
End Sub

Private Sub PageWaiter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        pageready = True
        RemoveHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    End If
End Sub
```

## End Region

So I was searching around internet for a module that could allow webbrowser1 to loads completely before proceeding next code, I found the code at [How to wait until WebBrowser is completely loaded in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275515/how-to-wait-until-webbrowser-is-completely-loaded-in-vb-net) , but I'm having some trouble with the accessibility, (on the module WebBrowser1.* and main form )it says on that not declared and it may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
I'm new to programming I hope someone could help me out.

here's picture links
http://s18.postimg.org/8qokcnzh5/Untitled.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your protection level error is caused because you must access the function `WaitForPageLoad()` in your module **WaitForPageLoad** from Form1's button click event

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.----------.org/login.php?")
    WaitForPageLoad.WaitForPageLoad() 'Example: ModuleName.FuncionOrMethodName()
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").InvokeMember("Click")
End Sub
```

1. You'll need to make your `WaitForPageLoad()` **public** so you can access it from **Form1**.
2. You will need to access your **WebBrowser1** using **Form1** (since your WebBrowser1 is located on your Form1

New `WaitForPageLoad()`

```
Public Sub WaitForPageLoad()
    AddHandler Form1.WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    While Not pageready
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    pageready = False
End Sub

Private Sub PageWaiter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    If Form1.WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        pageready = True
        RemoveHandler Form1.WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    End If
End Sub
```