# Gif not playing continuously in Webbrowser Control on Excel VBA Form while other code executes

Tags: excel, forms, vba, webbrowser-control, userform

I've created a form that is used to take user credentials, login our company's system and request exports. When the "Get Exports" button is clicked I display the gif (spinning wheel) and the text (first 'Establishing Connection' for when starting Internet Explorer instance, then it's supposed to change to 'Validating User Credentials'). The problem I'm running into is the gif isn't playing consistently and throughout the code execution after it is created/shown as I'd like it to.

**Form before click**

[image: 1]

**Userform code:**

```
Dim progresslbl As Object, progressbar As Object
Dim webBr As Object
'vbNewLine for linebreak in msgbox
Private Sub GetExports_Click()
    'Call FetchExports
    number = login.number.Text
    username = login.username.Text
    password = login.password.Text
    Label2.Enabled = False
    Label4.Enabled = False
    login.number.Enabled = False
    login.username.Enabled = False
    login.password.Enabled = False

    login.Height = login.Height * 1.02
    Set webBr = login.Controls.Add("Shell.Explorer.2", "x", True)
    With webBr
        .Navigate "C:\Users\Me\Dropbox\Macros\loadspinner.html"
        .Width = 12
        .Height = 12
        .Top = Label4.Top + 30
        .Left = 17.25
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Set progresslbl = login.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Progress", True)
    With progresslbl
        .Caption = "Establishing Connection"
        .Width = 150
        .Height = 21.75
        .Top = Label4.Top + 31.25
        .Left = 32
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Do While webBr.Busy Or webBr.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents 'Starts the loadspinner gif
    Loop
    DoEvents

'Call IE instance
Call GetIE
DoEvents
'Wait for system to get successful instance via loop that tests for control and number of tabs

progresslbl.Caption = "Validating User Credentials"

    login.Height = login.Height * 1.04
    Set progressbar = login.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Progressbar", True)
    With progressbar
        .BackColor = RGB(29, 104, 176)
        .Width = 10 '-> 150 finish
        .Height = 7.75
        .Top = Label4.Top + 47 '280
        .Left = 17.25
        .Visible = True
    End With
    DoEvents

'    Do While progressbar.Width <> 150
'        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
'        progressbar.Width = progressbar.Width + 5
'        DoEvents
'    Loop

'Proceed with login credentials and wait until we successfully get in (and don't receive popup)

End Sub
```

**Module code:** (I'm using IE Medium and this method due to my company's connection security sometimes losing connection with the object)

```
Sub GetIE()
    Dim targetURL As String: targetURL = "http://companywebsite.com"
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate targetURL

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    On Error Resume Next
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Do
        Set sh = New Shell32.Shell
        For Each eachIE In sh.Windows
            If InStr(1, eachIE.LocationURL, targetURL) Then
                Set IE = eachIE
                'IE.Visible = False  'This is here because in some environments, the new process defaults to Visible.
            Exit Do
            End If
        Next eachIE
  Loop
Set eachIE = Nothing
Set sh = Nothing

While IE.Busy  ' The new process may still be busy even after you find it
  DoEvents
  Wend

End Sub
```

Form after click

**Scenario 1:** The spinning wheel gif doesn't show until after `GetIE()` is complete

[image: scenario 1-1][image: scenario 1-2]

**Scenario 2:** The spinning wheel gif displays when it's first created, but the text stays stuck at 'Establishing Connection' even after `GetIE()` completes

[image: scenario 2]

I tried using the method provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32298026/2962937), but I couldn't get it working. Maybe it's because I'm using late binding?

**My Questions:**

1. How can I accomplish having the gif display (and play) continuously once I create/show it?
2. Am I using `DoEvents` correctly? I feel like I might be overusing it? How should I be using using `DoEvents`?
3. How can I make sure the text next to the gif changes accordingly (as each sub executes, example: `GetIE()`) and doesn't wait until the end and skips (or goes through the other text fast)?

Comment: `DoEvents` just passes control to the processor to execute any tasks/messages queued before returning control back to the executing code. It sounds like what you want would be *extremely* complicated in vba, because it's a single-thread execution, you can't have multiple jobs running at the same time. You might have more luck by making the form 'non-modal` if it isn't already and forcing a pause for the gif to load before resuming execution.

Comment: It appears all it took was changing the login form's modal property as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I know it's an old thread but how did you achieve that look of textbox?  it almost looks like HTML form.