# IE does not update after clicking on a link

Tags: .net, vb.net, internet-explorer

I have a simple code that uses the IE automation to login to a website (e.g., URL1) and then clicking on a link (e.g., URL2) and waiting until the new page gets ready and so on.
Here is the code:

```
'Part 1: Navigating to URL1
IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.visible = True
IE.Navigate(URL1)
Do Until IE.ReadyState = tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.DoEvents()
Loop
LinkSet1 = IE.document.all'Storing the current page's links only to help asking my question clearer :)



'Part 2: Entering user name and password and submit
IE.Document.All("UserNameElementID").InnerText = MyUserName
IE.Document.All("PasswordElementID").InnerText = MyPassword
IE.Document.All("SubmitElementID").click
Do Until IE.ReadyState = tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.DoEvents()
Loop



'Part 3: Search through links to detect a special id on the second page (URL2)
LinkFound = False
 Do Until LinkFound  
     LinkSet2 = IE.document.all'Storing the new page's links only to help asking my question clearer :)       
     For Each Link In IE.document.all
         If InStr(Link.id, "MYSecondURL_id") > 0 Then 
             LinkFound = True               
             Exit For
         End If
     Next
 Loop



'Part 4: Send a message to show that the second URL is found
MsgBox("Page loaded completely!")
```

My problem is that the above code worked finely when I used Windows 7 with IE 10. But when I updated to Windows 10 with IE 11, always LinkSet2 = LinkSet1 and an infinite loop occurs at Part 3. Any help would be appreciated in advance!

Comment: You should use a [WebBrowser Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms) instead of `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`. Note that the [Use of Application.DoEvents()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/1115360) could be causing problems in the program, see [How to wait until WebBrowser is completely loaded in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3275562/1115360) for a correct way to do something when the document load has completed.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Honestly, my code finally after loading several pages, clicks a link to download an Excel file. I first used WebBrowser Control for my purpose, but when clicked on the download link, it led to a "Server in Application" error and after about 1 week of struggling I couldn't solve the problem. Hence, I changed my way to use IE instead. It works completely right on Windows 7 and IE 10, but not on Windows 10 with IE 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Set window.onload = GetRef("WindowLoad")
Function WindowLoad
  Dim oElm 
Set oElm = document.getElementById("MYSecondURL_id")
if oElm Is Nothing then
    MsgBox("element does not exist")
else        
   MsgBox("element does exist")
end if
End Function
```

Because some of VBscript functions do not work on newer versions of IE.
And there is no doubt that IE is worst explorer in the history of internet surfing.

Comment: Thanks dear Nadir. Although this answer didn't solve my problem, but I agree that IE is the worst explorer! Hence, I switched to Mozilla and used Geckofx tool. That solved my problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using Until Link found. Which means that this loop will never end if there is no link. Instead. i suggest you to use only for each loop. And at the end of loop (When loop exited.) check if there is a link found or not. and perform action accordingly.

```
'Part 3: Search through links to detect a special id on the second page (URL2)
LinkFound = False 
 LinkSet2 = IE.document.all     
 For Each Link In IE.document.all
     If InStr(Link.id, "MYSecondURL_id") > 0 Then 
         LinkFound = True               
         Exit For
     End If
 Next
If LinkFound=True
'Do what you want to do if there is link
else
 'Do when there is no link in the page
End If
```

Comment: This method doesn't solve my problem, because it always enters the "else" condition. As I explained, LinkSet2 never updates and it's always the same as LinkSet1 (i.e., the links on the first page), although I see in the IE that the second page is loaded completely..

Comment: Check page manually if it contains something with ID you are searching.

Comment: No No, I know that the second page surely contains the link I want; the loop is only to make sure that the new page is loaded (because I want to click on that link to go to a third page!). The IE.ReadyState loop is not enough, because although it says that the page loading is completed but it's not :))