# How to get text from HTML element

Tags: html, vb.net

I have been trying off and on for the past couple of days to get the text from an HTML element into my listbox. 
The URL is https://www.roblox.com/users/88510187/favorites#!/places
and I am trying to scrape the favorite places of the user, for this instance the first would be "B is for build" here is what I have most recently tried and get nothing.

```
  Private Sub test3()
    Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each d As HtmlElement In divs
        If d.GetAttribute("className") = "text-overflow item-card-name ng-binding" Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(d.OuterText)

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I've changed the sub around many times playing with inner and outer text and Html but cannot seem to get just plain text. What on earth am I missing?

Comment: Not sure, but I think You should use `d.InnerHTML` instead `d.OuterText` ... btw. You can read more about `OuterText` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/outerText

Comment: Tried that one too, it acts like there is not a class with that name but there is, I listed them all out with  Dim PageElement As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement
            ListBox1.Items.Add(CurElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString())

Comment: You'ld get it with both `InnerHtml` and `InnerText`. When the Document is completed. You need to insert that code in the `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event.

Comment: Thats when the sub is fired, on document completed, maybe its not totaly done loading when it fires?

Comment: Yeap, You can see similar solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9205751/3279496

Comment: Yea, it wasnt loaded all the way, I added a  button and pressed after it loaded and it worked... 2 days trying and it was just that simple...

Comment: The `DocumentCompleted` event can be raised multiple times. You have to inspect the `WebBrowser1.ReadyState` property. You'll see that, possibly more than 1 time, it will be `WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive` instead of `WebBrowserReadyState.Completed`. And even then, sometimes you have to re-parse.

Comment: Is there a way to know when the WebBrowser control has stopped the process or quit changing the Html? I tried PaigeWaiter() and still doesnt load in time

Comment: In the document complete event, check the url of event that fires it, if e.url = webbrowser.url your html should be loaded and it should be ready to scrape.